# UPDATE via multiple group-rankings

Tags: mysql, sql

**The Basic Problem**

So I'm creating a service where customers sign up and receive mystery toys. Customers give us batches of orders (each order with its own price limit), and then we try to pair each individual order with what we *think* is the best toy that is also under that order's price limit.

Customers can update their preferences to narrow down the potential toys we send them; not every customer will be interested in every toy we have available. And of course, they don't want us to send them the same toy twice.

**The Question**

If I've got two tables: PotentialToys (that lists which toys can go to which customers, along with their price and ranked by estimated value) and ToyOrders (which has the customer, the price limit for each order, and the toy we plan to give them (default null, to be set on UPDATE)), how can I UPDATE the orders in table ToyOrders to choose toys that are both under that order's price limit and only chosen once per customer?

**An Example MySQL Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE PotentialToys (
    customer   NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    toy        NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    price      DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
    rank       INTEGER NOT NULL
 );

 CREATE TABLE ToyOrders (
   order_id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   customer     NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
   price_limit  DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
   rank         INTEGER NOT NULL,
   selected_toy NVARCHAR(25)
 );

 INSERT INTO PotentialToys (customer, toy, price, rank) VALUES 
 ('Alice', 'Chemistry Kit', 20.00, 1),
 ('Alice', 'Stuffed Bear', 5.00, 2),
 ('Alice', 'Playing Cards', 10.00, 3),
 ('Bob', 'Playstation', 500.00, 1),
 ('Bob', 'Baseball Monkey', 25.00, 2),
 ('Bob', 'Stuffed Bear', 5.00, 3),
 ('Bob', 'Chemistry Kit', 20.00, 4),
 ('Carlos', 'Magic Trick Set', 50.00, 1),
 ('Carlos', 'Playing Cards', 10.00, 2),
 ('Carlos', 'Banana-Phone', 20.00, 3);

 INSERT INTO ToyOrders (customer, price_limit, rank) VALUES 
 ('Alice', 20.00, 1),
 ('Alice', 15.00, 2),
 ('Alice', 10.00, 3),
 ('Bob', 25.00, 1),
 ('Bob', 25.00, 2),
 ('Bob', 15.00, 3),
 ('Carlos', 25.00, 1);
```

**The Desired Output After Updating ToyOrders**

```
SELECT order_id, customer, price_limit, selected_toy FROM ToyOrders;

+-------------------------------------------------------------
  | order_id | customer | price_limit    | selected_toy    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------
  | 1        | Alice    |  $20.00        | Chemistry Kit   |
  | 2        | Alice    |  $15.00        | Stuffed Bear    |
  | 3        | Alice    |  $10.00        | Playing Cards   |
  | 4        | Bob      |  $25.00        | Baseball Monkey |
  | 5        | Bob      |  $25.00        | Stuffed Bear    |
  | 6        | Bob      |  $15.00        | NULL            | -- No toys left for Bob under $15. It's OK to leave NULL
  | 7        | Carlos   |  $25.00        | Playing Cards   | -- The magic trick set cost more than the order's price limit, so he gets the next best thing
```

**What I've tried so far:**

```
SET @offset_rank = 0;
UPDATE ToyOrders AS O 
INNER JOIN PotentialToys AS PT 
    ON O.customer = PT.customer
    AND O.rank + @offset_rank = PT.rank 
    AND IF(PT.price <= O.price_limit, TRUE, (@offset_rank := @offset_rank + 1) && FALSE)
SET O.selected_toy = PT.toy;
```

The above only produces the correct output for Alice; Bob and Carlos end up receiving the wrong packages, like so:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------
  | order_id | customer | price_limit    | selected_toy    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------
  | 1        | Alice    |  $20.00        | Chemistry Kit   |
  | 2        | Alice    |  $15.00        | Stuffed Bear    |
  | 3        | Alice    |  $10.00        | Playing Cards   |
  | 4        | Bob      |  $25.00        | NULL            | -- Should be Baseball Monkey, not NULL
  | 5        | Bob      |  $25.00        | Stuffed Bear    |
  | 6        | Bob      |  $15.00        | NULL            | 
  | 7        | Carlos   |  $25.00        | Banana-Phone    | -- Should be Playing Cards
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: You should be constructing simpler problems to solve! ;-)

Comment: It seems a little unfair that Bob ends up with only two toys when he could have had all three just by reversing priorities.

Comment: I've be looking at recursive CTEs in MySQL-8.0 / MariaDB-10.2 so solve this and look at PotentialToys as a stock available rather than having a customer field.